# Output from which() statement suppressed in if statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data frame with the string "BLQ" in some of the cells. I can find out where these occur using:

```
which(df == "BLQ", arr.ind = TRUE)
```

In a particular example I am interested in, the length of the vector above yields

```
> length(which(df == "BLQ", arr.ind = TRUE))
[1] 492
```

If I execute the following:

```
  which(df == "BLQ", arr.ind = TRUE)
  stop("BLQ still present")
```

I will see all entries (rows and columns) where "BLQ" occurs and the program stops with the desired output:

```
Error: BLQ still present
```

But if I have the above enclosed in an IF statement:

```
if (length(which(df == "BLQ", arr.ind = TRUE)) != 0){
  which(df == "BLQ", arr.ind = TRUE)
  stop("BLQ still present")
}
```

The output from the `which` function is suppressed and I just see:

```
Error: BLQ still present
```

Why is that?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time we use `{ }`, we are creating a new enclosure. By default, R returns the result of an enclosure's last statement. In your example:

```
if (length(which(df == "BLQ", arr.ind = TRUE)) != 0){
  which(df == "BLQ", arr.ind = TRUE)
  stop("BLQ still present")
}
```

The `which` function returns an array of indices, but it isn't the last statement in the enclosure. The `stop` function, which is, returns nothing, which is why we see nothing when this code is run.

Conversely, the following code will return the indices as you expected, because `which` is the last statement:

```
if (length(which(df == "BLQ", arr.ind = TRUE)) != 0){
  which(df == "BLQ", arr.ind = TRUE)
}
```

You can force the output of `which` to appear with a `print` statement:

```
if (length(which(df == "BLQ", arr.ind = TRUE)) != 0){
  print(which(df == "BLQ", arr.ind = TRUE))
  stop("BLQ still present")
}
```

Incidentally, you can even capture the final result of the enclosure as you would any other function, i.e.:

```
a <- if (...) { 
  2 
}

a
[1] 2
```

Comment: Many thanks for that insightful explanation!